# What is "System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor+DateTimeUI"?

Tags: c#-2.0, system.componentmodel

Greetings,
doing research into outside code I got this control returning

```
 {
   Name = "DateTimeUI" 
   FullName = "System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor+DateTimeUI"
 }
```

to Type.GetType(). I've no idea what DateTimeUI is, and "DateTimeEditor+DateTimeUI" seems pretty confusing aswell. The class isnt defined in the code I was researching.

Googling yielded no relevant results except [this](http://www.webtropy.com/articles/type.asp?o=System.ComponentModel.Design), which didnt help; I'm all out of sources to draw from, and would appreciate any clarification on the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the class name `DateTimeUI` is a class nested inside the `System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor` class. If you need to dig in further - disassemble the code with RedGate reflector

Comment: Ditto, just was about to post when it said someone had posted an answer..+1